Collect output devices on c#
Previously i used this code to collect all output devices, but recently i update my code and know this code is not working at the moment because i receive this message error Installing "VisioForge.DotNet.Core.TRAIL" failed i would like know if exist a solution, for that problem.
for (int n = -1; n < WaveOut.DeviceCount; n++)
{
    var caps = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(n);
    Console.WriteLine($"{caps.ProductName}");
}

I would like a solution on c# Net.Framework.
Thanks

when you say ".net framework", you mean .NET Framework 4 ? Because it seems you are trying to install a .NET Core package (which is different from .NET framework)

You said you updated your code, but what did you change? What was working before and not working after?

@Pac0 i'm meaning .Net Framework 4.7.2 ... and the code i showed its from net framework. Recently i update all dlls and visioForge.DotNet.Core.Trail dont exist any more... with means, i cannot execute the code because the program dont have that library.

thanks, it's clearer now. The nuget page shows it should indeed be compatible with .NET framework 4.7.2 . Could you please copy into the question the full error message from Visual Studio? There should be more information on why the installation failed somewhere.

also, have you been changing the package source, something else than nuget.org ?

@Pac0 i only update all librarys on my project. Like VisioForge

are you able to rollback to the state before the update, using your source control, if you have setup some? (like git)
